# Can we see cluster endpoints priority statistics in GET /stats?

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm setting up envoy and i'm trying to use priority option in envoy configuration for giving the priority level to cluster endpoints. I want to see which priority level currently envoy is using in **/stats** . Can we able to see this?
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/endpoint/endpoint.proto